# Wine Regedit не сохраняет настройки даже по рутом

Tags: linux, wine, regedit, codepage

Обновил Linux Mint 21.3, перестала работать Wine. Установил заново. Хочу поменять Codepage с **1252,437 на 1251,866** так как в 1С буквы все вопросиками показывает.
Не могу сохранить изменения в реестре. Даже просто руками в файл **user.reg** вписывал. Всёравно не сохраняется. Запустил **sudo nemo** попробовал также результат аналогичен.
Не пойму с чем связано. На другом компьютере такая же проблема. но там даже линукс другой Fedora 37. Раньше таких проблем не возникало и в реестр не лазил. Сразу ставилась нормальная кодировка.

Comment: Wine никогда не должен работать под root это большими буквами написано в первых строках справки. Причина в несохранении настроек точно не в этом. Если исключить вариант что запускающий пользователь утратил права на каталог префикса. Раз вы говорите что работать перестало после обновления, то посмотрите ярлык запуска, возможно что сбросилась переменная WINEPREFIX и конфигурируете вы один префикс а программа живет в другом. Нужно запустить конфигурацию в префиксе программы. Очень часто иструкции по развертыванию ПО начинаются с создания префикса отдельного от умалчального

Comment: нет, с WINEPREFIX всё нормально. Пробовал и 64 и 32 результат одинаковый. Сейчас удалил папки .wine и .wine32 prefix32 и то же самое, пробую редактировать реестр, нифига не сохраняется. А, ещё при попытке переустановить программу пишет ошибку NSIS Error Launching installer. В инете пишут что проблема с инсталятором, но это не так. Ставил с него всегда и проверил установку на Windows 7 и Windows 11. Может версия Wine новая какаято глючная. Но ставил с оф сайта! На обоих Линуксах такая же фигня одинаковая. Причём Fedora с нуля установлена, а Mint обновлён.

Comment: Нашёл решение. NSIS Error Launching installer из-за того что в пути где лежит файл есть кириллица. Поменял, инсталятор запустился. Но запустился с знаками вопроса вместо русских букв. Нашёл решение LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 wine 1CSetup27.exe. Запустил из консоли. И потом также надо запускать программу чтоб буквы русские были. Не пойму как это прописать в ярлык на рабочий стол. Даже системную локаль сделал ru_RU.UTF-8 и не помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment[ru_UA]=
Comment=
Exec=LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 wine '/home/forever/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/1Cv77/BIN/1cv7l.exe'
GenericName[ru_UA]=
GenericName=
Icon=A3DA_1cv7l.0
MimeType=
Name[ru_UA]=1С Предприятие
Name=1С Предприятие
Path=
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

Вот решение, создал ярлык для запуска программы с необходимой кодировкой. Во всём виновата кодировка. Но не пойму что с ней произошло. Всегда была нормальная, а теперь странности какието. Реестр так и не сохраняет настройки! Но хоть программа теперь работает как надо.

UPD: В Linux Mint почему-то не сработал такой способ, пришлось искать обходной путь.
Создал файл вап

```
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
wine '/home/sergio/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/1Cv77/BIN/1cv7l.exe'
```

делаем его исполняемым

```
chmod +x run_program.sh
./run_program.sh
```

и наконец-то работает как надо.

Comment: Какую версию Wine вы используете?. Я на Debian поплюхался со стоковой версией и понял что там много лишних сложностей. WineHQ решает многие проблемы из коробки и является логическим продолжением стоковых версий. Проблема в том, что большинство сисадминов упираются рогами и не хотят ее разворачивать. На форумах самого  Wine создатели настаивают что проблем с сохранением быть не должно, за исключением переменных ключей Windows типа сериных портов. Однако есть тонкость. Если процесс не завершился то запись не выполнится. Что бы это проверить нужно перезапустить сервер: wineserver -k
winserver

Comment: Пробовал и WineHQ(с оф. сайта) и просто Wine(с репозиториев) абсолютно одинаково ведёт себя. Я ж говорю, что раньше такого не было ни  разу. Не пойму из-за чего.

Comment: Не пойму. В Fedora сделал без проблем и всё работает и с консоли и с ярлыка. В Mint не получается с ярлыка запустить. То же самое пишу. Что ж за..